# Testing for Infinite Content Length

Tags: java, url, streaming, content-type, checksum

I've been trying my hand at building a web crawler that generates checksums of the files it comes across.  I don't want to generate checksums for infinite streams (Internet radio, live video feeds, etc), because it would hang the crawler and eventually cause it to run out of memory.  Therefore, I need a way to filter these out.

I tried checking if `content-length` was set to -1, since streaming media do not report a content length, but found that many other servers choose not to report a content length on their documents, or use progressive downloads that do not report a content length.  My current solution is checking if the `content-type` is `video/*` or `audio/*` and `content-length` is -1, but that has the potential to throw out progressively downloaded media files that aren't of infinite length.

Is there an easy way to test if a stream is infinitely long without resorting to checking if it exceeds an arbitrary value?  My language for this project is Java with JSoup, if it matters.

Comment: Not too sure, but when there is a streaming response - you do not get the end of response, rather they just send you the data, so that the same response object can be used to send further streamed data. You can try checking, if response has ended which should be true in case of finite length media

Comment: @prabodhprakash Forgive me if I'm not grasping this, but if the data keeps on coming (like in an infinite stream), how will I know it's not going to end?

Answer (score 2):

If Content-Length is not present in response you could assume its stream if you see:

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

Comment: Thanks for that header; I can use it as part of the aforementioned heuristics.  Chunked encoding, however, is not inherent to infinite streams; the crawler could just as easily hit a progressive download that uses chunked encoding with no length (especially common for "virtual URLs").

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an easy way to test if a stream is infinitely long without resorting to checking if it exceeds an arbitrary value?

There is neither an easy way nor a hard way to tell with certainty how many bytes can be read from an arbitrary stream before its end is reached.  Indeed, even if a web server sends a response header indicating a particular content length, that does not guarantee that it will not send more content than advertised, or even that the content is finite.

Even if you use heuristics such as you describe, you need to be prepared to cut off content if it's longer than you are prepared to accommodate.

Comment: So your suggestion then is to continually read input until I hit an arbitrary buffer, assuming it meets the characteristics of streaming data (`transfer-encoding: chunked; content-length:-1`)?  Or I shouldn't trust the server for any transfer and throw heuristics out the window?

Comment: @ndm13 I see no reason why you shouldn't apply heuristics to avoid downloading resources that are marked as being infinite / too large.  You just cannot rely *exclusively* on that -- you need to be prepared to recognize and abort transfer of *any* resource that turns out to be too long.  And that shouldn't be a big deal, because it probably makes your code a bit simpler (vs. applying such treatment only to certain resources).